# Migrating data from legacy location for Android 11

Tags: android

I'm in the process of preparing our app (http://vespucci.io/) for targeting SDK 30/Android 11 in November. As it by its nature reads and writes non-media files that in many cases should be persistent and survive app de-installs, I've been investigating the options to maintain the functionality for our users.

According to https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#migrate_app_data the recommend option is to move such files to an app specific sub-directory of Download. However it would seem that both creating such a directory and accessing it depends on the deprecated https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String) or is their a non-deprecated way of doing this, that I've simply not found?

Comment: You can use the MediaStore to create files in such directories. Also the MediaStore can list files there. Further you have SAF.

Comment: You can also move to an app specific directory in public Documents directory. Deprecated? It works.

Comment: We use a wide range of files including such that cannot be used reasonable without random access (yes that would work in 11). Further because the files are typically supplied by the user / downloaded from third party sites, having -one- place for the files just makes sense from a user experience pov. Originally I had considered using the system provided app specific directories (even though not persistent), but since users can't navigate there with the SAF file picker in 11, that is out of the question. Deprecation is an issue because we don't want to move things around every other release.

Comment: `but since users can't navigate there with the SAF file picker in 11, ` Well they can. I posted code (the hack) for that. It even works in Android 12 to my surprise. Wel until now.

Comment: Without a link to the code that is a fairly useless comment. In my testing you can start out in the app specific directory, but once the user navigates away from it, there is no way to get back, which is, imho, unacceptable.

Comment: Without posting your test code that is certainly a useless remark ;-)